How do insurance policies with separate underwriters(?) work?
I have a condo insurance policy with GEICO that is separately underwritten (not sure of the precise term) by Travelers. If I want to get basically the same policy underwritten by Travelers, but not through GEICO, what should I do? Why isn't this something I can do directly through Travelers?

Travelers doesn't sell policies directly, they sell through agents. GEICO is the agent in this case. You can find another agent and check through them, maybe they can offer you something better.
